# unable to read value from pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

can't read data from void pointer:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef enum {
    ADDRESS,
    PERSON,
} DataType;

typedef struct {
    DataType type;
    void* data;
} Data;

Data* create_data(DataType type, void* data);

typedef struct {
    char* number;
    char* street;
    char* city;
    char* state;
    char* postalCode;
} Address;

typedef struct {
    int age;
    char* name;
} Person;

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nShowCmd
) {
    // WRITE

    Address* home = malloc(sizeof(Address));
    home->number = "123";
    home->street = "Main";
    home->city = "New York";
    home->state = "NY";
    home->postalCode = "10001";

    Data* addressdata = create_data(ADDRESS, &home);

    // READ

    char* addressstreet = ((Address*)addressdata->data)->street;

}

Data* create_data(DataType type, void* data)
{
    Data* d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    d->type = type;
    d->data = data;

    return d;
}
```

[image: memoryunread]

Comment: `create_data(ADDRESS, &home);` This passes an `Address **` into the call. You probably want just `home` there.

Comment: change `create_data(ADDRESS, &home);` to `create_data(ADDRESS, home);` will solve the problem

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler, and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your question, the first thing popped in my head is that *how can you dereference a void pointer since it has no object type*.

There's `parameter` mismatch in

> `Data* create_data(DataType type, void* data);` & `Data* addressdata = create_data(ADDRESS, &home);`

and instead of sending address of `home`, i.e. `create_data(ADDRESS, &home);` send `create_data(ADDRESS, home);`